# AWS Instance Type For 3,000+/Second Outgoing HTTP Requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, cloud

I'm currently scaling up an application on AWS, we send thousands of outgoing HTTP requests per second to 3rd party API's and services. Are there any EC2 instances optimized for this type of work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When work in aws, you need jump out of the idea as traditional way, because you needn't worry about if the instance is not suitable, waste money, etc.

Estimate how big traffic go out and you can start with a reasonable instance type, for example, `t2.medium`.

After running your application and keep monitoring the performance, if it is not good enough, just stop the instance, change the instance type, and start it again.

Here is the official document for [Resizing Your Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html)

That's all you need do, don't worry it from beginning.

Answer (score 1):

As usual on EC2 instance selection, it depends. Larger instances tend to have optimized network performance (see the "[instance type matrix](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#instance-type-matrix)"), but you many not need the CPU/disk/memory of larger instances.

Your best bet is to test your application, or a proxy for your application.

Comment: Right, this seems to be the case. We're using T2.Small instances right now that typically run at less than 10% CPU, but the network performance is definitely the bottleneck as our queue available messages quickly stack if we have any less than say - 10 instances consuming messages on the queue at a given time.

Comment: Running a slightly beefier instance doesn't yield cost:performance benefits either.

Comment: the great thing about using smaller instances is you get "cheap" stability by running more of them. I'd prefer 10 t2.smalls over 2 larger instances anyhow.

Comment: @tedder42 - I tend to agree with you, but I know others, often sysadmins with hard won experience, who hold the opposite view and would prefer one very well managed instance to focus on. It don't think there is a 'right' answer but it is an interesting debate! http://serverfault.com/q/58767